# Why is the this JMenu being displayed on this JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jmenubar

[This illustrates my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj29u.png)

Im trying to copy a paint like program but whenever I click on the screen the menu bar is displayed in the panel area.  It doesn't do it unless I click on the screen (to draw).  The menu bar is added before the panel, any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Main {
public static Frame frame;
public static Panel panel;
public static MenuBar menubar;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new Frame();
    panel = new Panel();
    menubar = new MenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    frame.addMouseMotionListener(panel);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);     
}
```

}

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
public Frame() {
    setTitle("Paint");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

}

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

public boolean isMouseDown = false;
public int x1,y1, x2, y2;
public Color colour = Color.BLACK;
public int size = 3;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(colour);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(size));
    g2.drawLine(x1 - 10, y1 - 80, x2 - 10, y2 - 80);
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
    x1 = x2;
    y1 = y2;
    x2 = arg0.getX();
    y2 = arg0.getY();
    repaint();
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    x1 = x2;
    y1 = y2;
    x2 = arg0.getX();
    y2 = arg0.getY();
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
```

}

```
public class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {

JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
JMenu brush = new JMenu("Pen");
JMenu colour = new JMenu("Colour");
Font font = new Font("Times New Romans", Font.PLAIN, 18);

public MenuBar() {  
   //JMenuBar Code here, left black as very long
}
```

}

Comment: Not related to your problem but:, 1) Don't call your classes Frame, Panel, MenuBar. Those are AWT class names and it becomes very confusing when trying to read your code. A class name should be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problems: You need to call `super.paintComponent(g);` within your paintComponent method. Else the JPanel cannot do its house-keeping painting of its own self.

If you want the drawings to persist, then either create an ArrayList of lines that are then drawn within paintComponent in a for loop, or better, paint onto a BufferedImage which is then displayed within the paintComponent method.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyPainting mainPanel = new MyPainting();
        MenuCreator menuCreator = new MenuCreator(mainPanel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyPainting");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuCreator.getMenubar());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPainting extends JPanel {
    private static final int IMG_W = 600;
    private static final int IMG_H = 450;
    private static final int STROKE_W = 3;
    private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(STROKE_W);
    private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private Color drawColor = Color.BLACK;

    public MyPainting() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(IMG_W, IMG_H));
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private Graphics2D g2 = null;
        private Point p0;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (img == null) {
                return;
            }
            g2 = img.createGraphics();
            g2.setStroke(STROKE);
            g2.setColor(drawColor);
            p0 = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (p0 == null) {
                return;
            }
            drawLine(e);

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (p0 == null) {
                return;
            }
            drawLine(e);
            g2.dispose();
            p0 = null;
        }

        private void drawLine(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p1 = e.getPoint();
            g2.drawLine(p0.x, p0.y, p1.x, p1.y);
            repaint();
            p0 = p1;
        }

    }

    public void setDrawColor(Color drawColor) {
        this.drawColor = drawColor;
    }

    public void clear() {
        img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        repaint();
    }
}

class MenuCreator {
    private JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    private MyPainting myPainting;

    public MenuCreator(MyPainting myPainting) {
        JMenuItem clearDrawing = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Clear Drawing") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (myPainting != null) {
                    myPainting.clear();
                }
            }
        });
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.add(clearDrawing);

        JMenu colourMenu = new JMenu("Colour");
        for (MyColor myColor : MyColor.values()) {
            colourMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction(myColor)));
        }

        menubar.add(fileMenu);
        menubar.add(new JMenu("Pen"));
        menubar.add(colourMenu);
        this.myPainting = myPainting;
    }

    public JMenuBar getMenubar() {
        return menubar;
    }

    private class ColorAction extends AbstractAction {
        private MyColor myColor;

        public ColorAction(MyColor myColor) {
            super(myColor.getText());
            this.myColor = myColor;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (myPainting != null) {
                myPainting.setDrawColor(myColor.getColor());
            }
        }
    }
}

enum MyColor {
    BLACK("Black", Color.BLACK), RED("Red", Color.RED), ORANGE("Orange", Color.ORANGE), BLUE("Blue", Color.BLUE);

    private String text;
    private Color color;
    private MyColor(String text, Color color) {
        this.text = text;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

}
```

Comment: this seems to work but this clears the screen every time?

Comment: @SamuelWeller: also you need to add the mouse listeners to the drawing JPanel, not the JFrame, else your pointer is off...

Comment: I was hoping to avoid storing each image but it certainly helps with drawing the lines and for changing the background so I will do.  Many many thanks

Comment: @SamuelWeller: again, you don't have to store the images if you create an ArrayList, but as the list gets filled up, the drawing may be a little less responsive.

Comment: @SamuelWeller: please see edit to code, now showing use of menus. Compile and run it to see how it works, and feel free to ask if any questions

Comment: Thank you so much for doing that, I need time to look over it but so many good ideas like using enum, mouse adaptor. <3

Answer (score 1):

You failed to honour the requirements of the paint chain...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(colour);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(size));
    g2.drawLine(x1 - 10, y1 - 80, x2 - 10, y2 - 80);
}
```

Apart from not needing to be `public`, one of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting. So, one of the first things you should do is call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super. paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(colour);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(size));
    g2.drawLine(x1 - 10, y1 - 80, x2 - 10, y2 - 80);
}
```

`Graphics` is a shared context, it is shared amongst the other components which need to be painted, so it is very important that you ensure that it's properly prepared before you paint to it.

It's also important that any significant modifications you make to the context (like transformations or rendering hints) are reversed before the method exists

I would recommend taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to gain a better understanding into how the painting system actually works

Comment: Thank you very much and thanks for the links, I will definitely take a look at them

Comment: Can't compete with mad programmer. Sigh. 1+ of course